# Error loading project Microsoft.WebApplication.targets

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017

I am getting an error loading project (.Net ver 4.5.2) in VS2017.

Error message:
The imported project "$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found....

[image]

How do I fix this?

Thanks,
Rashmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)，and you will see

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

This is different from previous versions of VS (like 2012 and 2013). Thus, if your project was created in those old versions of VS, you have to manually upgrade it.

Comment: This property group was missing. I am able to load the project after adding it. Thanks :)